# User Interface in a Navbar

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in HTML/CSS, So I am facing a problem while trying to integrate the user interface on the Navbar like this: [image].
I don't know how to style it, which tags should I use and how to put icon of user...

```css
/* Add a background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: #e61a26;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Add a color to the active/current link */

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #f1f3f2;
  color: #000;
}


/* Add a gray right border to all a items, except the last item (last-child) */

a {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

a:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Welcome <strong>Username></strong></p>
<p><a href="logout.php" style="color: red;">logout</a></p>


<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="/WWW/home.php">Home</a>
  <a href="/WWW/shortcode.php">Shortcode</a>
  <a href="/WWW/workorder.php">Work Order</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide us also your CSS

Comment: I did not succeed I don't know how to put a box on a navbar I tried with <a> and <li> tag. but I do not want it a link so i'am asking only for the tag that can insert the box on the navbar.
Thank you

Comment: @MrBuggy here it is !

Comment: @Paulie_D Hey :)  I succeeded  ! check my last answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few tries I succeeded it's really simple here is my code now :

```css
/* Add a background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: #e61a26;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Add a color to the active/current link */

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #f1f3f2;
  color: #000;
}


/* Add a gray right border to all a items, except the last item (last-child) */

a {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.workorder_link {
  border-right: none;
}

a:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="/WWW/home.php">Home</a>
    <a href="/WWW/shortcode.php">Shortcode</a>
    <a href="/WWW/workorder.php" class="workorder_link">Work Order</a>
    <a href="/WWW/logout.php" style="float: right;"> Logout</a>
    <a style="float: right; text-decoration: none;">Welcome <strong>Username</strong><img src="img/user.png" style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-left: 5px; width: 20px; height: 20px;"></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this with `flexbox`: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

There are also some special cases like the border on the last, which is invisible. For this use the `:last-child` selector to remove it from the last item. And to style the link to look like a normal text, use `text-decoration: none;` For the user image you can use the `img` tag. After you set your custom `width` and `height` use and `border-radius: 50%;` to make it automaticlly a circle.

Just study the flexbox guide and you'll see it isn't that hard. Hope this helps.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar__left,
.navbar__right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar__item {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar__item:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.navbar__item--active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.navbar__user-image {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.navbar__user-image,
.navbar__user-logout {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar__left">
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item navbar__item--active">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">About us</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar__right">
    <img class="navbar__user-image" src="https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/news/2016/08/23/106598324PandawaveNEWS_trans_NvBQzQNjv4Bqeo_i_u9APj8RuoebjoAHt0k9u7HhRJvuo-ZLenGRumA.jpg?imwidth=450" alt="user img">
    <span class="navbar__user-logout">user logout</span>
  </div>
</nav>
```